# Android: Limit the number of choices from the list of checkboxes

Tags: java, android, checkbox

In my app, I have multiple checkboxes from which I have to limit the user to 5 choices.
Afterwards - if he chooses another option from the checkboxes, it is not to been marked.

This is my code sketch -

```
Veg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (Veg.isChecked()) {
                if (result.length() == 10) {
                    finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);

                    Veg.setEnabled(false);

                } else {
                    result.append("1,");
                    System.out.println(result.length());
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: please put some more code.

Comment: The above code has been repeated for other items too.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use OnCheckChangedListener.
Keep all your checked checkbox ids in a arraylist, whenever a checkbox is checked, add it to arraylist, when unchecked remove, inside onCheckChanged event add a check for arralist.size() if its greater than 5 uncheck the checkbox by setChecked(false).

Comment: Please send me the specific code for the above problem as I am new to android.

Answer (score 0):

Same process for all checkboxes and use ArrayList for disable and enable checkboxes.

and below code is not good practice for programming.

```
Veg1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (Veg1.isChecked()) 
                {
                    counter++;
                    if (counter <= 10) {
                        do your process
                        call one of the method for ENABLE all uncheck checkboxes
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        counter--
                        Veg1.setChecked(false);
                        call one of the method for DISABLE all uncheck checkboxes
                    }


                       // Veg.setEnabled(false); remove this line

                } else {
                        counter--;
                        //result.append("1,"); remove this line

                    }
                }

            }
        });
```